# SQL Server XML/DataTable Insert - How to skip individual entity errors

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, datatable, bulkinsert

We can insert multiple rows to SQL Server by passing XML or DataTable from .NET application to a Stored Procedure. My question is that

- If 100 rows tried to insert like this and 1 row has produced errors, do remaining 99 rows would be inserted? or none of the 100 rows wouldn't be inserted as of a single row issue?
- Is there a way to interfere during above mentioned bulk insert so that we only to skip the rows which has errors?

Comment: What kind of errors are you seeing? What is inside your stored procedure that inserts into the database?

Comment: Data coming from external flat file and may contains wrongly formatted data inside some of the rows. But most of the rows will have valid data and should be inserted even-though wrong rows can be skipped.

Comment: Can you validate this data before you provide to the stored procedure and try to insert it? Then only attempt to insert data that is correct.

Comment: Data validation can be done based on information provided by the external file owners. If their file contains wrong data somehow, we don't want to skip all insert. This is a requirement.

Comment: Without more information about your XML, data which might be wrong, your insert process it is not possible to give you an answer, There are to many possible approaches. One might be to read and handle your data row-wise (`CURSOR` - but cursors are something one should avoid) or to insert your data into an error tolerant staging table, do further validation and insert from there.